# Android PreferenceScreen set title

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm creating a nested preference screen (ie with another PreferenceScreen object in it)

I can set a title to the secondardy PreferenceScreen using the .setTitle method

What I'm ideally wanting is the first preference screen that shows a link to the 2nd preference screen to have a different title.

e.g
The top level preference screen is called:

SMS Messages

Inside SMS Messages I want:

```
  Sound Options
  Vibrate Options 
  Misc Options
```

But when I get to the secondary screen I want the title to be

```
 "SMS Messages - Sound Options"
```

It seems there's only one property that can be set - which is "setTitle" and this shows as the link on the first preference screen and the title on the 2nd preference screen.

Is there anyway to differentiate the two?